# Exit customer from welcome Journey - After click/subscribe

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions, list, automation, subscriber

I am trying to launch a welcome series with the intent to get the subscriber to fill out their profile. I am using Journey builder to do it.

I want to exit the Jounrey when the subscriber visits the profile center and fills out their information. I can't find an event that would trigger that that exit.

I've tried:

- Setting the master Data Extension as the exclusion list... but this isn't possible as I can only choose specifically made suppression lists.
- Creating an Exit Criteria (but nothing checks against DE)
- Creating engagement split... but I can only check "clicks" not if they filled out their profile.

Any suggestions helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the out-of-the-box profile center and a data extension as your Entry Event source. You also mentioned a Master Data Extension so I’m also assuming you are storing the profile information in this data extension. You have two options as I see it:

- Add the Master Data Extension in **Contact Builder > Data Designer** so that you can use it in the Decision Split as Contact data. The Decision Split will then know if your subscriber has filled out their profile information
- Or query the profile data from the Master Data Extension into the Journey Data Extension and then use the Journey data in the Decisions Split